# Swift + Autolayout: Rotate UILabel, keep it next to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I would like to have a UILabel attached to another UIView, currently layed out with AutoLayout.

What I would like to achieve is the following:

[image]

But if I only rotate the view, it's rotated around the center point, and if I change the anchor point, the upper view moves. How do I have to layout the two views with autolayout first and then make the rotation?

Currently, autolayout does the following:

[image]

With the following code:

```
    label.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    label.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(-45 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)), 0, 0, 1)
```

I do get something like

[image]

Comment: First I think your anchor point should be (0,1) instead of (0,0) > https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html (different in iOS and OS X).

Comment: How your views are attached? By which constraints? Can't you transform the label instead of the layer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't change the anchor point, because that will mess up autolayout.

Instead, compensate for the anchor point's position in your transform:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        updateTransform()
    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        updateTransform()
    }

    private func updateTransform() {
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: -labelSize.width / 2, y: labelSize.height / 2)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: -CGFloat(slider.value) * CGFloat.pi / 2)
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: labelSize.width / 2, y: -labelSize.height / 2)
        label.transform = transform
    }

}
```

Result:

[image: demo of rotated label]