# How to Customize price button text in swift, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, button, xcode-storyboard

I have 2 `UIButton` as shown in below image. Here I need to customize exactly the same for both, mean texts, how could I do this.

Suggest how could I do this either in storyboard (using label/view ..) or programmatically. Guide me with some piece of code for `NSAttributtedstring` in case of label or button text as shown in image.

[image]

Comment: Just use simple UIs with the storyboard. Don't over complicate it.

Comment: choice is urs, its my suggestion use NSMutableAttributedString for superscript (use UIButton). and use UIlabel with transform(for e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063225/swift-autolayout-rotate-uilabel-keep-it-next-to-uiview)

Comment: @RJE, I have to use these buttons dynamically, means price changes according to region. so I cannot use simply an image to customize it..

Comment: I mean either use a button with NSAttributedString as Anbu suggested above or use UIViews and UILabels and change them based on received values. Anyway its a simple UI arrangement with the storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this below **func** :

```
extension UILabel {
    func setAttributes(price : String) {
        let font:UIFont? = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)
        let fontSuper:UIFont? = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        let aDotRange = (price as NSString).range(of: ".")

        let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: price, attributes: [.font:font!])

        attString.setAttributes([.font:fontSuper!,.baselineOffset:5], range: NSRange(location:0,length:1))

        attString.setAttributes([.font:fontSuper!,.baselineOffset:5],
                                range: NSRange(location:aDotRange.location,length:4))
        attString.setAttributes([.font:font!],
                                range: NSRange(location:1,length:aDotRange.location - 1 ))
        attString.setAttributes([.font:fontSuper!],
                                range: NSRange(location:aDotRange.location + 4,
                                               length: (price.count) - (aDotRange.location + 4) ))
        self.attributedText = attString
    }

}
```

**Dummy code** :

```
lblPrice.setAttributes(price: "$249.99 / mon")
lblPrice.layer.cornerRadius = 4
lblPrice.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
lblPrice.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

lblPrice2.setAttributes(price: "$999.99 / 6 mo")
lblPrice2.layer.cornerRadius = 4
```

**Output** :

[image]

Comment: it show use of unresolved identifier price  in ur dummy code 1st line ..How to fix that ?

Comment: @Aleesha Check now.

Comment: Thank you very much.. almost done!!..it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIViews` and `UILabels` for designing the buttons and add tapGestures to the `UIViews` for User interactions.